# Unable to getting response from broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am not getting any response from broadcast receiver in the code below every time the control goes to this case named `ACTION_NO_RESPONSE_FOUND_TERMINATE`.
I'm connecting via Bluetooth getting this response.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadCastReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(BleService.SAMPLE_RESPONSE_FOUND)) {
            Toast.makeText(LightConfigurationActivity.this, "Response found is : "+intent.getStringExtra(BleService.COMMAND_RESPONSE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        switch (action) {
            case BleService.ACTION_LAST_RESPONSE_FOUND:
                if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        showSuccessPopUp();
                    }
                },15000);
            }
            break;
            case BleService.ACTION_CHECKSUM_MATCH_FAILED:
                if (mIsActivityRunning) {
                resendconfig();
            }
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            break;
            case BleService.ACTION_GAT_FAILED_TO_RECIEVE_ACKNOWLEDGMENT:
                /**
                * ToDo : Need to remove Toast notification.
                */
                if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                if (mIsActivityRunning) {
                    showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.failed_to_get_response_from_device));
                }
                break;
            case BleService.ACTION_NO_RESPONSE_FOUND_TERMINATE:
                if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to get acknowledgment. Please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case BleService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED:
                if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Toast.makeText(LightConfigurationActivity.this, R.string.disconnected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

From BleService getting response from intent Action_no_response_found

BleService.java:

```
private void broadcastUpdate(String action, BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, scanRecord);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(String action, String address, int status) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STATUS, status);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(String action, String response) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    intent.putExtra(COMMAND_RESPONSE, response);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```